# Using ArrayAdapter crashes app every time. Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to dynamically set the values in a list. Originally this was taking place in the `onCreate` event itself. Thinking that perhaps the `ListView` object hadn't been initialized yet I moved this to a button click event. This simple example blows up nicely every time I tap the button with the "Unfortunately, `ListViewTest` has stopped" and no exception stack trace to be found. Also worth noting is that the real target app does not blow up until that `ListView` becomes visible when the container tab is tapped.

I am using a fully updated Android Studio 2.0 with the Nexus (5X API 23) emulator on El Capitan 10.11.4.

Any tips will be appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.greencountrytechnical.listviewtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                       onYouTappedMe();
                                   }
                               }

        );
    }
    private void onYouTappedMe()
    {
        String[] noob={"why","does","this","not","work","?"};
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        if(lv != null) {
            List<String> lvs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(noob));
            // lvs is not null and it is filled with the values from the     array.
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.activity_main, lvs);
            if(adapter != null)
            {
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.greencountrytechnical.listviewtest.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where your problem probably lies;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     R.layout.activity_main, lvs);
```

You can fix this by either creating your own list_item_layout or use what android gives you by default:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lvs);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I missed the android prefix. It works. I have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept the answer.

Comment: Please make sure you place this android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 and then clean your project. It is available. If not working again, rebuild your project